# IE browser shakes when launched by the webdriver script

Tags: selenium-webdriver

IEDriver: 2.39, 2.46, Selenium WebDriver: 2.45.

The issue is whenever I try to execute the scripts in IE browser the browser fluctuates during the script execution. I tried with a couple of IE drivers and Selenium WebDrivers but no use. Could anyone provide me the solution for this issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "fluctuated"? Do you mean the window size or something?

Comment: I mean the browser is getting jerk[shaking] during the execution of the script

Comment: Have you tried using the latest IE driver v2.48.0.4 ?